# Shopping cart session adding not work with some page URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

On direct pages my shopping cart is work, e.g. links : `http://sriads.com/shopping/latest/` (`index.php`).

But it's not working with these links, it's coming from `.htaccess`:

```
http://www.sriads.com/shopping/product/13/tp-link-4-port-wireless-dual-band-n600
```

The popup box also works, but not the shopping cart. What is happening for this? I've seen the problem, it works with the non-www form of the domain, but not the www address.

This link does not work:

```
http://www.sriads.com/shopping/product/13/tp-link-4-port-wireless-dual-band-n600
```

Here is my code `ajax.php` (it's a jQuery popup box):

```
session_start();
require '_include/core.inc.php';

require_once("_include/dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

function checkCartForItem($addItem, $cartItems) {
     if (is_array($cartItems)){
          foreach($cartItems as $key => $item) {
              if($item['id'] === $addItem)
                  return $key;
          }
     }
     return false;
}

$cart_id = $_POST['id']; 
$qtyget = $_POST['quantityValue'];

if (!empty($_POST['quantityValue'])) {

    $qty = $_POST['quantityValue'];
} else {
    $qty = 1;
}

//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
//Item name     
'id' => $_POST['id']    

);

$addItem = $_POST['id'];

if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    if (!empty($qty)) {

        $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["id"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["product_name"], 'id'=>$productByCode[0]["id"], 'quantity'=>$qty, 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["new_price"]));

        $itemExists = checkCartForItem($addItem, $_SESSION['cart_item']); 

        if ($itemExists !== false){ 
            // item exists - increment quantity value by 1 
            $_SESSION['cart_item'][$itemExists]['quantity']++; 
        } else { 

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {

                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["id"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $qty;
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }

        } 

    }
}
```

.htaccess (in `http://sriads.com/shopping/product/`)

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shopping/product/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*)$ ./load.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?id=$1
```

---

internal pages redirect to www but session page in /ajax.php not redirect to www

i used .htaccess for home

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: I've tidied up your post, so it is more readable, including removing "please help" and "plz" - we try to discourage begging and txtspk here. Would you add your `.htaccess` file into the question, so people can see if that is the cause of the problem?

Comment: thanks for this i added that

Comment: OK, so there's your domain-specific rules. What do they do? I take it `!^www\.` means "the following rules apply to domains that do not start with `www`", is that right?